# Want to use pivot-wider but it's not really working

Tags: r, tidyr

My original data looks like this:
[original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pWftz.png)

It's a very long dataset, the # of sections repeat every 10 times. I tried to pivot the data to a format like this:
[desired format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RXed.png)

When I use pivot-wider, it gives me Nas all over.... How can I get the data pivoted?
Here's the original data:

```
df1 <- structure(list(ID = 1:60, Num_of_section = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), Data = c(123L, 434L, 
545L, 2323L, 54L, 23L, 54L, 24L, 53L, 44L, 132L, 44L, 543L, 335L, 
53L, 33L, 42L, 24L, 35L, 55L, 12L, 143L, 533L, 344L, 232L, 5332L, 
23L, 333L, 56L, 75L, 123L, 434L, 545L, 2323L, 54L, 23L, 54L, 
24L, 53L, 44L, 132L, 44L, 543L, 335L, 53L, 33L, 42L, 24L, 35L, 
55L, 12L, 143L, 533L, 344L, 232L, 5332L, 23L, 333L, 56L, 75L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-60L))
```

This is the input I'm getting now:

```
noa <- structure(list(X..of.section = 1:10, `1` = c(123L, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `2` = c(NA, 434L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), `3` = c(NA, NA, 545L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), `4` = c(NA, NA, NA, 2323L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `5` = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 54L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `6` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, 23L, NA, NA, NA, NA), `7` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 54L, 
NA, NA, NA), `8` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 24L, NA, NA), 
    `9` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 53L, NA), `10` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 44L), `11` = c(132L, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `12` = c(NA, 44L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `13` = c(NA, NA, 543L, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), `14` = c(NA, NA, NA, 335L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), `15` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 53L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), `16` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 33L, NA, NA, NA, NA), `17` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 42L, NA, NA, NA), `18` = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 24L, NA, NA), `19` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 35L, NA), `20` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 55L), `21` = c(12L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), `22` = c(NA, 143L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    `23` = c(NA, NA, 533L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `24` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, 344L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `25` = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 232L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `26` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    5332L, NA, NA, NA, NA), `27` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    23L, NA, NA, NA), `28` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 333L, 
    NA, NA), `29` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 56L, NA
    ), `30` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 75L), `31` = c(123L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `32` = c(NA, 434L, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `33` = c(NA, NA, 545L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `34` = c(NA, NA, NA, 2323L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), `35` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 54L, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), `36` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 23L, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), `37` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 54L, NA, NA, NA), `38` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 24L, NA, NA), `39` = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 53L, NA), `40` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 44L), `41` = c(132L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), `42` = c(NA, 44L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA), `43` = c(NA, NA, 543L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
    ), `44` = c(NA, NA, NA, 335L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `45` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, 53L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `46` = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, 33L, NA, NA, NA, NA), `47` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 42L, NA, NA, NA), `48` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    24L, NA, NA), `49` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 35L, 
    NA), `50` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 55L), `51` = c(12L, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `52` = c(NA, 143L, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `53` = c(NA, NA, 533L, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), `54` = c(NA, NA, NA, 344L, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA), `55` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 232L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA), `56` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5332L, NA, NA, NA, NA), 
    `57` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 23L, NA, NA, NA), `58` = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 333L, NA, NA), `59` = c(NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 56L, NA), `60` = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, 75L)), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And this is the desired output:

```
output <- structure(list(X = 1:10, `1` = c(123L, 434L, 545L, 2323L, 54L, 
23L, 54L, 24L, 53L, 44L), `2` = c(132L, 44L, 543L, 335L, 53L, 
33L, 42L, 24L, 35L, 55L), `3` = c(12L, 143L, 533L, 344L, 232L, 
5332L, 23L, 333L, 56L, 75L), `4` = c(123L, 434L, 545L, 2323L, 
54L, 23L, 54L, 24L, 53L, 44L), `5` = c(132L, 44L, 543L, 335L, 
53L, 33L, 42L, 24L, 35L, 55L), `6` = c(12L, 143L, 533L, 344L, 
232L, 5332L, 23L, 333L, 56L, 75L), `7` = c(123L, 434L, 545L, 2323L, 
54L, 23L, 54L, 24L, 53L, 44L), `8`= c(132L, 44L, 543L, 335L, 
53L, 33L, 42L, 24L, 35L, 55L), `9` = c(12L, 143L, 533L, 344L, 
232L, 5332L, 23L, 333L, 56L, 75L), `10` = c(123L, 434L, 545L, 
2323L, 54L, 23L, 54L, 24L, 53L, 44L), `11` = c(132L, 44L, 543L, 
335L, 53L, 33L, 42L, 24L, 35L, 55L), `12` = c(12L, 143L, 533L, 
344L, 232L, 5332L, 23L, 333L, 56L, 75L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-10L))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this; it will pivot your data wider, and name the columns X plus X1 to X6.

```
pivot_wider(
  df1 %>% mutate(ID = ceiling(ID/10)) %>% rename(X = Num_of_section),
  names_from=ID,values_from = Data,names_prefix = "X"
)
```

Output:

```
       X    X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1   123   132    12   123   132    12
 2     2   434    44   143   434    44   143
 3     3   545   543   533   545   543   533
 4     4  2323   335   344  2323   335   344
 5     5    54    53   232    54    53   232
 6     6    23    33  5332    23    33  5332
 7     7    54    42    23    54    42    23
 8     8    24    24   333    24    24   333
 9     9    53    35    56    53    35    56
10    10    44    55    75    44    55    75
```

If you really want X1 through X6 to be replicated, you can assign the result from above to `df1_wide`, and do this:

```
bind_cols(
  df1_wide,
  df1_wide %>% select(-X) %>% rename_with(~paste0("X",7:12))
)
```

Output:

```
       X    X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9   X10   X11   X12
   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
 1     1   123   132    12   123   132    12   123   132    12   123   132    12
 2     2   434    44   143   434    44   143   434    44   143   434    44   143
 3     3   545   543   533   545   543   533   545   543   533   545   543   533
 4     4  2323   335   344  2323   335   344  2323   335   344  2323   335   344
 5     5    54    53   232    54    53   232    54    53   232    54    53   232
 6     6    23    33  5332    23    33  5332    23    33  5332    23    33  5332
 7     7    54    42    23    54    42    23    54    42    23    54    42    23
 8     8    24    24   333    24    24   333    24    24   333    24    24   333
 9     9    53    35    56    53    35    56    53    35    56    53    35    56
10    10    44    55    75    44    55    75    44    55    75    44    55    75
```